# TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function when running Jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

In a simple setup to get going with testing React components with Jest, I'm getting the error "TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function" on each test run, with `npm test`

The actual React page builds fine and renders with no errors.

I've looked at the other posts related to this error, but none that can help with this issue seem to be specific to Jest.

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Here's my setup:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-bed",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.10.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "webpack": "4.22.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestComponent from './components/TestComponent';

ReactDOM.render(<TestComponent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

src/components/TestComponent.js

```
export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <p>I'm v0.0.1 of TestComponent</p>
        )
    }
}
```

__ tests __/test-component.snapshot.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import TestComponent from '../src/components/TestComponent';

TestComponent('should display component version', () => {
    const comp = renderer.create(<TestComponent/>);
    let tree = comp.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: Do you have babel-jest properly configured in your jest.config under the transform property?

It should look like this:  
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
},

Comment: I didn't, but adding it didn't solve the issue. Thanks anyway @JayKariesch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
TestComponent('should display component version', () => {
    const comp = renderer.create(<TestComponent/>);
    let tree = comp.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

It's interpreting this as you wanting to call the `TestComponent()` function

Change it to something like:

```
describe('TestComponent', () => {
  it('should display component version', () => {
    const comp = renderer.create(<TestComponent/>);
    let tree = comp.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks Jake. That did the trick. Must have been following some out of date (or just incorrect) examples. Much appreciated.